# Can't access Administrator account on Windows XP after adding local user account

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts, administrator

I have an installation of windows XP, and it's not part of a domain. Previously, it just had only the administrator account, and upon creating a different user account, all access was lost to the administrator account. When the machine starts up, only the new local account is offered for login, which seemed strange.

I've checked that the administrator account was not disabled, nor are any rights missing from the local security policy. Furthermore, the administrator account is accessible via remote desktop, where an opportunity is given to type the desired account. REALLY strange.

Upon deletion of the new local user account, the administrator account appeared again. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the expected behavior. The Administrator account is only available on the Welcome screen if there are no other user accounts. Once you create a user account the Administrator account is removed from the Welcome screen. If you want to log on as Administrator when another user account exists you need to disable the Welcome screen.

Comment: I thought if you press ctrl+alt+del twice from the welcome screen you can then log in as the administrator, it's been awhile though.

Answer (score 1):

or you can press ctrl+alt+del and get the login box

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl+Alt+Delete twice at the welcome screen to bring up the login box.  You can type in administrator there.